# Need a method to obtain code that would construct a given expression tree

Tags: c#, code-generation, expression-trees

There are two ways to construct an expression tree in C#:

1. let the compiler rewrite a lambda and store the result;
2. construct it piecewise, calling factory methods provided by the `Expression` class.

The first approach is simple, but it doesn't let me integrate already existing subexpressions into a resulting expression, which is my main goal. (These subs are passed to me as function parameters by design).

In fact, the second approach itself *is* the subexpression composition process, but it is *very* cumbersome for anything but the simplest expressions with little to no nesting involved.

So, to get the best of two ways, while having to construct the trees piecewise, I look at copiler-generated expressions, and use them as hints. What I do is: write the code to construct a tree, while looking at the given tree. The whole process is quite a routine, so I wonder:

- are there tools to automate that? Couldn't find any myself.
- aside from codegens, are there some other possibilities to improve my method and make it more productive?

Here's the explaination of *why* I need this strange process at all.

```
Expression<Func<IEnumerable<N>, IEnumerable<N>, IEnumerable<N>>>
    MyExpression = (src1, src2) => 
        src1.SelectMany(outer => lookup[outer.Value1].Select(
                inner => new N(outer, inner)));
```

Now, I am provided with two subexpressions, which are to be placed instead of `outer.Value1` and `new N(outer, inner)`. I can't use `.Compile()` and utilise them as lambdas, because I have to provide the complete expression tree for further processing intact. I need a way to integrate them into `MyExpression`, and the only method I'm aware of is to construct the whole tree via `Expression` factories. But with more complex queries it gets extremely complex and error-prone.

Comment: I don’t understand your question. You want something that converts lambda expressions into code that creates expressions? Why? Give an actual example of what you’re trying to solve please.

Comment: Build your own parser that builds trees?  See my SO answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25106688/120163

Comment: @poke so that I could edit them, of course =) I need it for a Linq library which is heavily expression-based, and the compositions are quite bulky sometimes.

Comment: @IraBaxter Yep, I consider writing one... But it will require me to study the subject a bit more, so I decided to ask first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> aside from codegens, are there some other possibilities to improve my method and make it more productive?

Basically you'd want to write a class that extends [ExpressionVisitor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expressionvisitor(v=vs.110).aspx) that replaces some component of one expression with pieces from the other expression.

> are there tools to automate that?

[LINQKit](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx) does just that. From the website's examples:

```
Expression<Func<Purchase,bool>> criteria1 = p => p.Price > 1000;
Expression<Func<Purchase,bool>> criteria2 = p => criteria1.Invoke (p)
                                             || p.Description.Contains ("a");

Console.WriteLine (criteria2.Expand().ToString());
```

Output:

> p => ((p.Price > 1000) || p.Description.Contains("a"))

Comment: Thanks! Looks like a solution, I'll dig into it now. The only concern for now is that LINQKit depends on EntityFramework (at least that's what NuGet says). The project I work on is a lightweight library, which would rarely be used with EF, and making its users depend on EF is an overkill...

Comment: @vines The original LINQKit (which you can download from the author's site) doesn't require EF. The maintainer of the NuGet package suggested to me to use [an older version of it](https://www.nuget.org/packages/LinqKit/1.0.0) if you don't want that dependency on EF 6.